# Executing Google Script without any authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, google-sites

I would like to ask if it's possible to execute a Google Script on a Google Site without asking for permissions?

1. Step of permission[image]
2. Step of permission[image]

The part of code that needs permission is this:

```
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
```

Is it possible to get access to a spreadsheet without asking for permissions?

The script will only need read access to the spreadsheet and the spreadsheet is shared with everyone.

Comment: You can use `urlFetch` to access sheets api. You won't need Drive access, but you would need "access external url" permission.

Comment: The Google Script must be published as "Anyone, even anonymous" under "Who has access to the app."  That's the only way that you can avoid the authorization prompt.  There are many ways to configure sharing and publication.  Who owns the spreadsheet?  Who owns the script?

Comment: Also, `//@OnlyCurrentDoc` will highly downsize the permissions requested, if you didn't know already.